# How to "require" a JS class that contains JSX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to call functions of my JS class which extends react.
I have one file `RunTest.js` which looks like this:

```
let Builder = require('./Builder');
let b = Builder();
b.say("Hello World!");
```

My `Builder.js` in the same directory looks something like this:

```
class Builder extends React.Component{
    ...
}

module.exports = { Builder }
```

And when I run with `node RunTest.js` I receive the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ node RunTest.js
/Users/jonahlibrach/Documents/project/prototypes/bron/v1/java/prototype/
server/static/protocol/Builder.js:322
                        <div class="navbar">
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810
:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jonahlibrach/Documents/project/prototy
pes/bron/v1/java/prototype/server/static/protocol/RunTest.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810
:10)
```

How do I use this class in node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use modules that contain [JSX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/babeljs/babeljs_working_babel_with_jsx.htm) in Node.js without first transpiling them to JavaScript (e.g. with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx)).